# how to check if given page is active page

Tags: menus

I am building my own custom menu for custom post type.
I have a loop and I need to know if given item is active one.

How to this properly? How to compare if given items address (slug, permalink, id or some other appropriate option) is the one that is currently loaded?

```
$args = array('post_type' => 'services');
$services = new WP_Query( $args );
$cnt = 0;
if( $services->have_posts() ) {
    while( $services->have_posts() ) {
    $services->the_post();
    // HOW TO CHECK IF $services is the active page?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `get_the_ID()` before you start the loop, then compare:

```
$original_id = is_singular() ? get_the_ID() : 0;

$args = array('post_type' => 'services');
$services = new WP_Query( $args );
$cnt = 0;
if( $services->have_posts() ) {
    while( $services->have_posts() ) {
    $services->the_post();
    if ( get_the_ID() === $original_id )
        echo 'This is me!';
```